# php include - alternative with better url

Tags: php, url

i want to build a website with different views, but a stable header and footer - no problem so far. But i dont like the kind of urls i got at the moment with the php GET method. 
My site at the moment works like this (what istn working properly):

```
$_page = $_GET['p'];
if ($_page == "city-sitemap"){ include "views/city-sitemap-view.php"; }

if ($_page == "place"){ include "views/place-view.php"; }


else { include "views/index-view.php";}
```

this isnt a very sweet solution but i dont know a other for now. I tried to use a mvc framework but failed dramatically. So everytime i add a link i use for example this "index.php?p=place" - not very nice. 
The including of the views isn very smart as well? is there a better way?
I would like to use something like the rewriteEngine that the new url is like a folder.
Can you help me to find a better solution?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent simple framework, you can just use the routing if you like: http://fatfreeframework.com/home

Comment: Does every page have its own view file? If so, you might look into standardizing your view file to get its data from a database.

Comment: yeah almost. some pages get different content from database already
i dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

### Page including

For the page inclusion, you can use a simple array to dynamically allocate your page to a specific name. As so:

```
$pages = array('city-sitemap'=>'views/city-sitemap-view.php',
    'place'=>'views/place-view.php',
)

if(array_key_exists($_GET['p'], $pages){
    include $pages[$_GET['p']];
}else{
    include 'views/error.php';
}
```

This array should be added in a general configuration file. With this configuration if you want to display your city-sitemap-view.php view, you will have to write this url: http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=city-sitemap

### Url rewriting

It is possible to rewrite an URL with a .htaccess file. Here is an example of code you would can to write in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

An url that looks like this:

> http://www.domain.com/index.php?p=city-sitemap

will be converted to this one:

> http://www.domain.com/city-sitemap

Comment: thanks for your answer. how does the url look after the .htaccess rewrote it?

Comment: uhh i like the new url - to link to a view i use the position number of the view in the array?

Comment: @Philibobby your array syntax is messed up and this could do with a way of handling non existent pages

Comment: Sorry about the typos, I fixed it and added some error handling!

Answer (score 0):

There is something called the [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) that you should look into. You can write a very simple one yourself. It works in conjunction with [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). If for example your url looks like this:
    /mypage.html

the url rewriter will reroute the request to index.php .

Index.php will then look at the URL and do somehting like this:

1) break the page out into string, ignoring .html extention

```
 preg_match("\/(.*?)\.html", $_REQUEST['URI'], $matches);
 $pageClass = $matches[1];
 //$pageClass = "mypage"
```

2) look for and load a class named "Mypage.php"

```
 $controller = new $pageClass();
```

3) call the run method on the page class, passing it all the request parameters

```
 $request = new Request($_REQUEST);
 $controller->run($request);
```

you can then do all the page specific stuff inside your controller class that is specific to the page.

At each simple step along the way, you will find you want to do more and more things like authentication, filtering, tracking, etc. You will get end up developing a front controller that is specific to your needs, as well as a base Controller class that does a bunch of standard stuff that all your controllers have in common.

Comment: if i would understand that i would use a mvc framework. sorry

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, i really think you should consider the framework i linked, (it is very logical) or any other micro framework, but if you really wish to do this yourself then you can handle your includes like so:

```
<?php  //index.php
$requested_page=isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'home';

//maybe have this included from pages.php for organization
$pages=array(
    'home'=>'home_content.php',
    'about'=>'about_content.php',
    'contact'=>'contact_content.php'
);

include "views/header.php";
if(array_key_exists($requested_page, $pages)){
    include "views/".$pages[$requested_page];
}else{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    include "views/error404.php";
}
include "views/footer.php";
```

This keeps your pages in a single array, and protects against arbitrary inclusion vulnerabilities.

For nicers urls, see The other users .htaccess rewrite rules